# Help replacing last occurrence of char with new char

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was able to replace the first occurrence of a `,` but now I want to remove the last occurrence.

```
    $(function() {
    $(".defaultUL li").each(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        if(text.indexOf("...")<0) {
        var s = text.lastIndexOf(",");
        $(this).html(text.replace(s," "));
        }   
    });
});
```

Substituting `","` for `s` is not working like I hoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't the first parameter of replace supposed to be the string you're replacing, not the index where you want to do the replacing?

Try

```
$(this).html(text.substring(0, s) + " " + text.substring(s+1));
```

Comment: pefect, except in my case `s-1` should just be `s` or it crops off the `,` and the char before it.